# Lost all connection via Putty and RDP after upgrading to ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu

I'm a beginner in Ubuntu. I had a RDP connection to connect from my Windows10 to a VM with Ubutnu server v. 16.04.5

I launched an upgrade to ubuntu 18 using these commands:

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt dist-upgrade

sudo do-release-upgrade

The system made its upgrade, and then closed automatically my RDP connection.
Since then, I could not re-connect with my IP address.

This is [the error message on RDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11GbJ.png)

and here [the error message on Puttty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2yeY.png)

I read in some links on askubuntu suggesting some commands related to ssh. The issue is that I currently have no access to the ubuntu server to make any of these commands.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:

1. edit sshd_config:

   > sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

change PasswordAuthentication and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to yes.

2. restart ssh:

   > /etc/init.d/ssh restart

Answer (score 0):

Try the configuration for `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The primary network interface
auto example
iface example inet static
address 192.168.?.?
netmask 255.255.255.?
gateway 192.168.?.?
dns-nameservers 192.168.?.?
```

? for your own values

Comment: from my side, I don't find any way to access the command line in ubuntu. what should I do ?

Comment: open a terminal and run this command: sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces hope this will work